# Finding the most repeated value for each associated attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm practicing some SQL and I thought about the following problem:

For each pub find the time when more people go.
I have the following tables:

```
            GOESTO
id_person   id_pub  time
1           1       Daytime
2           2       Night time
3           3       All Day
4           1       Daytime
5           2       Night time
6           1       All Day
7           3       Daytime
8           3       Night time
9           3       Night time
10          1       Night time
```

```
         PUB
id_pub  pub_name    cost
1       pub1        123
2       pub2        324
3       pub3        345
```

What I want to get is something like the following:

```
pub_name   time
```

I think I should use MAX and COUNT functions, but I'm not quite sure how should I do it. It should work in an Oracle database.

Thank you!

Comment: COUNT should be in the statement , also you will have to use a 'HAVING' clause instead of a where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WITH mydata AS (
      select id_pub, "TIME", count(*) as cnt
      from GOESTO
      group by id_pub, "TIME"
) 
SELECT m.id_pub, m."TIME", m.cnt
FROM mydata m
JOIN (
   SELECT id_pub, max( cnt ) as cnt
   FROM mydata
   GROUP BY  id_pub
) x
ON (m.id_pub = x.id_pub AND m.cnt = x.cnt);
```

or this one

```
SELECT id_pub, "TIME"
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           dense_rank() over (partition by id_pub order by cnt desc ) rnk
    FROM (
          select id_pub, "TIME", count(*) as cnt
          from GOESTO
          group by id_pub, "TIME"
    ) t
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

To get names instead of `id_pub` values you need to join the above queries with `PUB` table

```
SELECT p.pub_name, q."TIME"
FROM (  one_of_the_above_query )q
JOIN PUB p
ON p.id_pub = q.id_pub
```